# my npm-lint is throwing error "missing script: lint"

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run npm run locally, and ran npm init, that created package.json. Here is my package.json

```
    "name": "ironic-ui",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "======================== Team and repository tags    ========================",
    "main": "test-shim.js",
    "directories": {
    "doc": "doc"
   },
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ironic-ui"
  },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
 }
```

Is there missing something? Or do i need to install something more? I am getting an error "Missing script: lint"
Thanks

Comment: What command are you running that results in the error message?

Comment: npm run lint path_to_the_file_name.js

Answer (score 15):

You need to setup linter and add lint command in your package.json
Many linter are available. Assuming you setup eslint
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

it would look something like this

```
// package.json
{ 
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have like this, "lint": "eslint --no-color ironic_ui/static"

Comment: get rid of `ironic_ui/static` part and try again `npm run lint path_to_the_file_name.js `

Comment: @roxxypoxxy This is simpler: `"lint": "eslint"`

Comment: @RyanZim That's true and will work, but I usually local scope my scripts just make sure I use the same version that is defined in my package.json, not the global :)

Comment: @roxxypoxxy The local installation always takes precedence over the global in a script

Comment: Ahh gotcha..thanks for this info. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If i remove that "ironic_ui/static" then i am getting the error http://paste.openstack.org/show/612582/

Comment: @roxxypoxxy getting the above error, it is saying missing node_modules

Comment: @user3339691make sure you have installed `eslint`. `npm i eslint -S`

Comment: @roxxypoxxy: i installed that and this is the error i am getting http://paste.openstack.org/show/612888/

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-openstack' means that you'll need to install that too `npm i eslint-config-openstack -S`, `-S` to save that to package.json

Comment: @roxxypoxxy: Sorry, somehow stack overflow did not notified me about the message. I installed the package as you suggested, and also installed eslint-plugin-angular and it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 13):

Add this script to your package.json file:
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ."

Comment: "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint" without space and period at the end worked for me

Answer (score 10):

**Should not be removing eslint, instead should try to configure it to make it work to your preferences.**

However, if you need to remove it because of time or other constraint

1. From `firebase.json` delete `"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"`
2. From `Package.json` delete `"lint": "eslint .",` (should be within the scripts:)
3. Also from `Package.json` delete these `devDependencies`

```
"eslint": "^7.6.0",
"eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0"`
```

4. Delete this file from repo `.eslintrc.js
5. Then run `npm i`

**then you should be able to run `firebase deploy`**

Comment: Great Work. Fixed my problem.

Comment: Works for me! Flutter||Firebase||Cloud Functions||Firebase Messaging

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove eslint from your Firebase Functions project, you can go to `firebase.json` and delete the line `npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint` (inside `predeploy`). After this, you can delete the `.eslintrc.json` file inside your functions project

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem.

I deleted functions folder, `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json`.

Then reinstalled firebase-tools

```sh
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

After `firebase init`, chose functions, it asked

> Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable .....?.

I typed `No`.

It worked fine for me.

Comment: Or simply remove `"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"` from `firebase.json`'s `predeploy`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when after setting up a firebase functions project inside a project that already had a firebase function elsewhere. It seems that `firebase init` doesn't necessarily know which project to set as "source" in firebase.json.

In my case, firebase.json simply pointed to the wrong source dir. I corrected it to point the my intended directory - issue solves.

Note: In my case, linting was desired, so removing linting was *not* the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same problem when I do: 
    firebase deploy --only functions
(-- only functions is optional), it redirects me to

```
npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint
```

It worked fine for me when I removed lint, thus having:

```
npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run
```

only.

Comment: "Removing lint" is never an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

For me i was just running the command without entering the function folder so it was not finding it i was just running this function on the project folder. So run **cd function** in your cmd if your are just in the project folder then run the command again but if the script is not in your package.json as mentioned above or you said no to eslint/lint when you initialized your firebase project lint wont work but others command that exist in your scripts work.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `package.json` from `"lint": "eslint .",` to `"lint": "eslint",` worked for me.